# Forward SNMPTRAP to specific community doesn't work

Tags: redhat, net-snmp, snmptrapd

**CONTEXT**

Forward SNMP trap received by snmptrapd service to specific Community.

You can see my lab scheme :
[MyLabScheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38aDJ.png)

**VERSIONS USED**

Servers : RHEL 8.7

SNMP : NET-SNMP version 5.8

SNMP Version : 2c

**WITH WHICH CONFIGURATION**

I have created the most simple configuration for the lab :

*[Server A]*

/etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf

```
snmpTrapdAddr udp:161
authCommunity   log,execute,net public
```

*[Server B]*

/etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf

```
snmpTrapdAddr udp:161
authCommunity log,net public
forward default ServerCip:161 public
```

*[Server C]*

/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

```
agentAddress udp:161
rocommunity public default
```

Trap is received successfully on Server B but i received nothing on Server C in /var/log/messages and in `tcpdump port 161` either.

I have tested on server B to change this setting by removing the Community :

```
forward default ServerCip:161
```

It's works but this is not my purpose, i need to forward to this IP only if specific Community is received.

*QUESTION*

I've looked at the various forums and the initial parameter that i set : `forward default ServerCip:161 public` seems to have already been used, but given the dates of the many posts I assume that this option no longer exists in recent versions of net-snmp.

I could use the TrapHandle parameter with a script that does a loop but I don't know how to extract the "variables" from the snmp traps received and forward the SNMP trap from Server A.

In have searched in `man snmptrapd` they talk about variables like %P but I don't think that's possible to catch it.

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Nobody knows ?
Am i not precise enought ?

I can re-explain if necessary.